# Trying to use Fuse to mount HDFS. Can't compile libhdfs

Tags: ant, hadoop, mount, fuse, hdfs

I'm attempting to compile libhdfs (a native shared library that allows external apps to interface with hdfs). It's one of the few steps I have to take to mount Hadoop's hdfs using Fuse.

The compilation seems to go well for a while but finishes with "BUILD FAILED" and the following problems summary -

commons-logging#commons-logging;1.0.4: configuration not found in commons-logging#commons-logging;1.0.4: 'master'. It was required from org.apache.hadoop#Hadoop;working@btsotbal800 commons-logging

log4j#log4j;1.2.15: configuration not found in log4j#log4j;1.2.15: 'master'. It was required from org.apache.hadoop#Hadoop;working@btsotbal800 log4j

Now, I have a couple questions about this, in that the book which I'm using to do this doesn't go into any details about what these things really are.

1. Are commons-logging and log4j libraries which Hadoop uses?
2. These libraries seem to live in $HADOOP_HOME/lib. They are jar files though. Should I extract them, try to change some configurations, and then repack them back into a jar?
3. What does 'master' in the errors above mean? Are there different versions of the libraries?

Thank you in advance for ANY insight you can provide.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using cloudera hadoop(cdh3u2), you dont need to build the fuse project.

you can find the binary(libhdfs.so*) inside the directory $HADOOP_HOME/c++/lib

Before fuse mount update the "$HADOOP_HOME/contrib/fuse-dfs/src/fuse_dfs_wrapper.sh" as follows

**HADOOP_HOME/contrib/fuse-dfs/src/fuse_dfs_wrapper.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

for f in ${HADOOP_HOME}/hadoop*.jar ; do
   export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:$f
done

for f in ${HADOOP_HOME}/lib/*.jar ; do
   export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:$f
done

export PATH=$HADOOP_HOME/contrib/fuse-dfs:$PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$HADOOP_HOME/c++/lib:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.26/jre/lib/amd64/server/
fuse_dfs $@
```

LD_LIBRARY_PATH contains the list of directories here
"$HADOOP_HOME/c++/lib" contains libhdfs.so and
"/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.26/jre/lib/amd64/server/" contains libjvm.so 
`\# modify /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.26/jre/lib/amd64/server/` as your java_home

Use the following command for mounting hdfs

```
fuse_dfs_wrapper.sh dfs://localhost:9000/ /home/510600/mount1
```

for unmounting use the following command

```
fusermount  -u /home/510600/mount1
```

I tested fuse only in hadoop pseudo mode not in cluster mode