# Hadoop fuse on multinode

Tags: hadoop

I need to use hadoop fuse to mount HDFS on a multi-node cluster. How can I achieve that? 
I have successfully deployed fuse on a single-node cluster, but I doubt it would work on multi-node. Can anyone please throw light over this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't matter, whether your cluster is single node or multinode. If you want to mount HDFS on a remote machine, make sure that particular machine has access to cluster network. Setup a hadoop client(with the same hadoop version in cluster) in the node in which you are planning to mount HDFS using FUSE.

The difference while mounting is namenode url.
(**dfs://NAMENODEHOST:NN-IPC-PORT/**)

In case of single node namenode url would be localhost(0.0.0.0/127.0.0.1/0), but in multinode cluster you have to give namenode Hostname/Ip address instead of localhost. It's possible to mount hdfs in any linux machines which can access hadoop cluster.

[Trying to use Fuse to mount HDFS. Can't compile libhdfs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6699851/trying-to-use-fuse-to-mount-hdfs-cant-compile-libhdfs)